# member site suggestions

Tags: members

I wondered if anyone could suggest the best direction to take for this site.

The site is mainly a site with members profiles.  Members will add a profile and others will search through their profiles.  The members will fill out a short form with bio/contact/ and other information.

IS it best to have everything in member fields using something like Solspace User or have a simple member form and have all the content in a channel entry?

What sort of things do I need to consider in making this choice?  I will want to be able to sort and filter the members profiles with items such as categories etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an add-on like [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/), [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) or [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration) which all use channel entries for their members. You'll then be able to treat members like you would any other channel. (Safecracker, etc)